# An online service I could query for a name of a random historical figure

Tags: javascript, node.js

I decided that it's time to get rich and famous, so I'm building a tool that generates Hollywood movie titles. I plan to sell them for money.

Example movie name: *Abraham Lincoln: Vampire Hunter*.

Basically, I would take a name of a famous historical figure and combine it with a respectable profession to get the name of a movie.

There is a problem, though. I don't know all the names of historical figures, and I sure would mind writing them all down by myself. **So, is there an online database or service I could query, that would return the name of a random historical figure?** How would I do it in Javascript (node.js)? The professions I can come up with myself.

**Edit:** I'm looking for something that has an API.

Comment: @Bane Frankly, with your username, I'm expecting something Batman-related.

Comment: Well, I chose my nickname long before I knew who Bane from Batman was... It's from *Durin's Bane*, one of the names by which the Balrog in Moria went by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out [DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/About). It offers a [SPARQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL) endpoint interface to Wikipedia's data, and returns machine-readable results formatted as [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework).

Don't be put off by RDF and semantic-webby stuff... for simple queries, you can parse the RDF as XML and handle it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_celebrities

http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biographies_of_famous_Americans

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wealthiest_historical_figures

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_100

Answer (score 0):

This one also looks pretty good:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/historic_figures/

Not sure if they have an API though! ;)